# MySQL Storing Friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql, relationship

What is the best practice for storing friend relationships with MySQL?

I currently have:

```
FRIENDSHIP ID | FRIEND1_ID | FRIEND2_ID | STATUS | DATE_ESTABLISHED

       1             1          2        accepted         now()
       2             1          3        incoming         now()
       3             1          4        outgoing         now()
```

But would it easier to manipulate in PHP by storing a 2-way relationship for each friendship such as:

```
FRIENDSHIP ID | FRIEND1_ID | FRIEND2_ID | STATUS | DATE_ESTABLISHED

       1             1          3        incoming        now()
       2             3          1        outgoing        now()
```

Which would turn into:

```
FRIENDSHIP ID | FRIEND1_ID | FRIEND2_ID | STATUS | DATE_ESTABLISHED

       1             1          3        accepted        now()
       2             3          1        accepted        now()
```

If I keep it as is, what queries would I need for:

- inserting a new relationship (user 1 adds user 2)
- listing only incoming friend requests for user 1

Comment: Well, here we go: *did you try anything?*

Comment: Drop the `friendshipID` and don't store redundant data

Comment: If it's not required to use mysql i would use a graphdb instead.

Comment: Both ways are fine.

Comment: Instead of 1 and 2 you should probably communicate the directionality of this relationship, plus what kind of records are involved. Is "friend" actually a "user"? `user_friending_id` and `user_friended_id` communicate more than what you have here, but that's just one example.

Comment: I can't identify what kind of difference you think it makes to use either the first or the second example. The first example talks about users 1,2,3,4, the second example only has users 1 and 3. If the tables should show "the same", I'd expect them to only deal with the same user. Can you write in your own words what the different approach would be?

Comment: Since someone closed this as broad (it's not): Insert:`INSERT INTO Friends (FRIEND1_ID, FRIEND2_ID, STATUS, DATE_ESTABLISHED) VALUES (1, 3, 'incoming', NOW()), (3, 1, 'outgoing', NOW())`
 Update: `UPDATE Friends SET STATUS = 'accepted' WHERE (FRIEND1_ID =1 AND FRIEND2_ID=3) OR (FRIEND1_ID =2 AND FRIEND2_ID=1)` also if you want the date to update on accept set that too.

Comment: Thanks guys, was simply asking for advice rather than a specific answer, thought one method could have advantages.

Answer (score 1):

Store your users:

```
ID | USERNAME
```

Store the friendships:

```
USER_ID1 | USER_ID2 | STATUS | DATE_ESTABLISHED
```

bonus point: this schema allows for non mutual relationships :-)

Also, I wouldn't update the "status" field when the status changes. What I would do is to create a new row with the new status. This way you have the history of the statuses and you can also efficiently search for the "current friendship" (sorting by timestamp)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Perhaps whoever did it can explain.